# How to get Property Id, View Id and Account Id programmatically?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I would like to know how to get the Property Id, View Id, and Account Id from Google Analytics after authenticating, using PHP or JavaScript?  As I want to be able to store them in a database.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by looking at the [Google Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) which has endpoints to retrieve Account, Property and View ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Account Summaries API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) endpoint. It returns the full tree